# insert value of select form into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, html-select

I have a form that adds vehicles to a database, there are 2 drop down select fields in the form, 'Make' and 'Model'

When I select an option from either one to insert it into the stock table in the database the make 'ID' or model 'ID' gets inserted into vehicle make / model rather than the name of the vehicle make, so '3' gets inserted instead of 'Volkswagen'

Here is some of my code

```
<form action="addstock.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="make">
<div id="field1">Make:</div> <div id="field2">
<select name="mke" id="mke">
        <?php
            include 'includes/db2.php';
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM make";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $res = "<option ";
                $res .= "value='".$row['code']."'>";
                $res .= $row['vehicle_make'];
                $res .= '</option>';
                echo $res;
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mke').change(function(){
        var code = $(this).val();
        var data = 'code='+code;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "fill.php",
            data : data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $('#mdl').html(html);
            }

        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Code for the model drop down option, the rest of the code for this is on another page (fill.php)

```
<div id="field1">Model:</div> <div id="field2">
<select name="mdl" id="mdl">
    <option selected="selected">Model</option>    
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

fill.php page

```
if(isset($_POST['code']))
{
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM model WHERE MakeCode = '".$_POST['code']."'";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0 )
        {
            echo '<option>No Results</option>'; 
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $res = "<option ";
                $res .= "value='".$row['id']."' >";
                $res .= $row['vehicle_model'];
                $res .= "</option>";
                echo $res;
            }
        }
}   else {
    echo '<option >error</option>';
}

?>
```

Back on the addstock.php page here is the insert code

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['addstock'])){

    $mke = $_POST['mke'];
    $mdl = $_POST['mdl'];

    $addstock = "insert into stock (veh_make,veh_model) values('$mke','$mdl')";

    $addsto = mysqli_query($con, $addstock);

    if($addsto){

        echo "<script>alert('Vehicle has been added')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('addstock.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to php and not sure how to insert the name instead of the id, as when I am trying to display a vehicle on another page the ID's show like 3 4, instead of Volkswagen Golf

Hope you understand what I mean

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Replace `$res .= "value='".$row['code']."'>";` with `$res .= "value='".$row['vehicle_make']."'>";`  and similar replacement should be applied to the model select box

Comment: you should store an id, and have an id-name table to use for display

Comment: Action is not needed when you are using ajax.. According to your code, form tag is also irrelevant. You are not posting the form..

Comment: is `MakeCode` a unique value in your table??

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the result of a SELECT statement that gets you the make and model:

```
"insert into stock (veh_make,veh_model) select make.vehicle_make, vehicle_model FROM make, model WHERE make.id=$mke AND model.id=$mdl"
```

But this is wrong DB design. `stock` should not contain make and model names, but rather IDs, references to rows in other tables, or Foreign Keys.